# Rails change locale with dropdown table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, select, rails-i18n, setlocale

I've been following rails getting started tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html for my first rails application.

I want to be able now to change language of the site. I've also followed this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html and have everything working.

Now, I want to set up a drop down table to let the user choose the language using a simple select like this:

```
= select "Site", "language", options_for_select([[t(:english), 'en'], [t(:spanish), 'es']])
```

But I'm not understanding how to save/submit what the user selects.

For example, I have a basic WelcomeController

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

And its index view with the select:

```
h1 = t(:welcome_header)
= link_to t(:goto_blog), controller: 'articles'
= select "Site", "language", options_for_select([[t(:english), 'en'], [t(:spanish), 'es']])
```

(it's all following as I said the getting started guide).

So, am I using the select correctly? How do I submit and then change the locale with what the user selects there?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

**index.html.haml**

```
= form_tag welcome_path do
  = select_tag 'set_locale', options_for_select([[t(:english), 'en'], [t(:spanish), 'es']])
  = submit_tag 'submit'
```

**welcome_controller.rb**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:set_locale]
      redirect_to welcome_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    end
  end
end
```